# Websites which offer a comparison of loans in Austria not in German

Tags: austria, loan

I'm Italian, and I've been living in Austria for seven months. Since I don't speak German, I need some help finding a website for loan terms comparison in Austria preferably in Italian.

I've found a wonderful website which makes this kind of comparison but unfortunately it's only for Germany: http://www.check24.de/kredit/onlinekredit/

I've tried to find it via a [Google search](https://www.google.at/search?q=Vergleichsportal,%20%20Kredit,%20austria&oq=Vergleichsportal,%20%20Kredit,%20austria&aqs=chrome..69i57.8335j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) but it is not exactly what I was looking for.

the problem is that for me is like Arabic.. in Italy we have TAN and TAEG interest tax. The second is comprehensive of everything (insurance, expenses, and so on). - In Austria (?). A good answer could include at least one example..

Comment: If you use Chrome, it has the option to auto-translate webpages into your default language. The translations are sometimes weird but with the help of an online dictionary such as dict.leo.org or dict.cc and with repeated visits to a particular website, you will start to remember the translations.

Comment: (http://www.bankkonditionen.at/produkte/kredit.cfm) That's the first result in your google search and the first result I found. It seems to be quite the same as the German site. You have to click on the type of loan you need and then it shows you a comparison of the different offers. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @drat: I've found this: https://www.creditnet.at/home.html and https://durchblicker.at/ratenkredit and this http://www.easybank.at/

Comment: @drat: the problem is that is like arabic.. in italy we have TAN and TAEG interest tax. The second is comphreensive of everything (insurance, expences, and so on). - In Austria (?). A good answer could include at least one example..

Comment: @Revious okay, maybe you should specify that in your question, because the example German website doesn't indicate those different interest rates either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such websites exist in English. Use the Google Translate functionality built into Google Chrome to use German comparison sites.